# Проблема с отправкой и приёмом кириллицы

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пытаюсь получить сообщение от бота. Вызываю /help, но ничего не происходит.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['help'])
def help_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')
```

Если изменить текст сообщения на 'Hello', то всё отлично отправляется. 
Да, и если текст сообщения оставлять тем же, что и прислал собеседник:

```
message.text
```

то сообщение на русском языке возвращается нормально.

Comment: попробуйте `u'Привет'`

Comment: @NickVolynkin пробовал. SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0:invalid continuation byte. В консоли отображается как u'╧Ёюсютры'. В заголовке если что # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 1):

Помогло

```
unicode('Привет', 'cp1251')
```

С utf-8 почему-то не получалось.

Comment: Увы так тоже не работает(

Comment: @Denisoed: автор вероятно на Windows записал файл в cp1251 кодировке (ANSI code page на русcкой Винде), на что указывает SyntaxError при попытке декодировать в unicode при наличии `coding: utf-8`. То есть фактически у автора строка равна: `b'\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'`. Чтобы убедиться, можно `u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'` строку использовать. То есть следует использовать unicode, а чтобы можно было писать `u'Привет'`, необходимо сохранять файл в кодировке, которая согласуется с coding: объявлением наверху файла.

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в начало скрипта : # coding: utf-8

Comment: В комментарии под вопросом есть такая фраза: _В заголовке если что # -- coding: utf-8_.